# Using manytomany field as foreignkey in the other class under model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Models.py

Here I am trying to use the attribute: working_hours which is manytomany - as a foreignkey in other model
please help me sort the concern if possible

```
class AvailableTime (models.Model):
    available_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.available_time)
    
class AttendantAvailability(models.Model):
    attendant_name_choices=[('AN1',"Ipsum Lorem"), ('AN2',"Lorem Lorem"),]
    
    attendant_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=attendant_name_choices)
    def attendant_name_lookup(self):
        for choice in self.attendant_name_choices:
            if choice[0] == self.attendant_name:
                return choice[1]
        return ''              
        
    booked_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    working_hours = models.ManyToManyField(AvailableTime)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.working_hours)
    
    
class ServiceDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(ServiceName,  null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, default = None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    preferred_time = models.ForeignKey(AttendantAvailability)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.preferred_time)
```

This isn't working for me !! I need to use the Manytomany field "working_hours " as the foreignkey in other class

```
ERROR:

self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\User\Service_Management\Salon_Services\models.py", line 45, in <module> class ServiceDetail(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\User\Service_Management\Salon_Services\models.py", line 122, in ServiceDetail
preferred_time = models.ForeignKey(AttendantAvailability)
NameError: name 'AttendantAvailability' is not defined
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? The fields for the AttendantAvailability model are not indented correctly. Are all these models in the same file?

Comment: Thank you for that note. I 've fixed the indentation in the post.